# SQL with concats and Joins works ok in MySQL 5.1 but returns NULL on 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

I'm having problems with an SQL that runs perfect in my local server but return null values when running in my hosting (godaddy).

This is the code:

```
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  a.title, 
  GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CAST( t.id AS CHAR( 50 ) ) ,  ':', t.name ORDER BY t.id SEPARATOR  ',' ) AS  'tags', 
  GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CAST( i.id AS CHAR( 50 ) ) ,  ':', i.fileName ORDER BY i.id SEPARATOR  ',' ) AS  'images'
FROM 
  articles a
JOIN 
  article_tags ta ON a.id = ta.articleId
JOIN 
  images i ON a.id = i.articleId
JOIN 
  tags t ON ta.tagId = t.id
WHERE 
  a.id = :id
```

It basically gathers data from an articles table and get its associated tags and images from other tablers.

When I run it on my local server, I get this:

```
┌-----┬------------------┬----------------┬------------------------┐
│ id  │ title            │ tags           │ images                 |
├-----┼------------------┼----------------┼------------------------┤
│ 1   │ some article     │ 1:php,2:jquery │ 1:pic.jpg, 2:other.jpg |
└-----┴------------------┴----------------┴------------------------┘
```

Instead, when I run it on my hosting:

```
┌-----┬------------------┬----------------┬------------------------┐
│ id  │ title            │ tags           │ images                 |
├-----┼------------------┼----------------┼------------------------┤
│ 1   │ some article     │ NULL           │ NULL                   |
└-----┴------------------┴----------------┴------------------------┘
```

Any idea on what's the issue here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a difference in versions between your local machine and the host?

Comment: Either there is some difference in version  or id doesn't exist in your table on sever.

Comment: @JayBlanchard  yep, you're right, Mine is mysql 5.1 and server's is 5.5

Comment: @anantkumarsingh The id exists, the tables in my local machine and the server are the same.

Comment: Now you have to check out syntax because of version change

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I'm looking into it, can't find the difference so far.

Comment: apparently the issue is arounf the JOINs... If I replace with LEFT JOIN, I get the images right... but the tags column still NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it has to do with MySQL version (5.1 vs. 5.5).

Replacing the "JOINs" with "LEFT JOINs" did the trick.